# Show that function has local unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g \in C^1 (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and let $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear map  with $h(1)\neq0$.
$t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ are given.

$$u'=g'(t) \cdot h(u),~~ t ∈ \mathbb{R},$$
$$u(t_0) = u_0.$$

Show that the function has one local unique solution.

How can I show that this thing only has one local unique solution? The linear map with $h(1)\ne 0$ confuses me a bit. I got h(u)=au for some a from a previous question but still no clue about this one.
I mean I need to show that the partial derivative $f_u(t,u)$ is continuous on $R^2$ I guess but this thing still confuses me.

Comment: The condition $h(1) \neq 0$ is equivalent to the condition that the linear map $h$ is not the zero map.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your answer, we have that $h(u)=au$ for some real constant $a$. As Travis notes, $h(1)\neq 0$ tells us that $a=h(1)\neq 0$, so $a$ is a non-zero real constant and $h$ is not the zero function, so $u'$ is not uniformly $0$.

Writing $u'=\frac{du}{dt}$, we can apply a separation of variables argument to rewrite the differential equation as

$$\frac{du}{u}=ag'(t)dt.$$

Integrating both sides (LHS from $u_0=u(t_0)$ to $u(t)$, RHS from $t_0$ to $t$), we obtain

$$\log (u) - \log(u_0) = ag(t)-ag(t_0).$$

Hence

$$u(t)=u_0e^{ag(t)-ag(t_0)}$$

at least in some small neighborhood where our integration was valid. One can easily check that this is a local solution, and by construction it is the only possible one. Hence we have a unique local solution.

Comment: thanks I pretty much figured out myself too after some time but appreciate the clarifaction and the time you took for the answer. Thanks alot. Just wasnt really sure if h(u) = au can be written into the formula and just integrating by it actually is allowed and works. After the answer I guess its ok haha